# A recipe for a winter version of a wheat beer?

Tags: beer, wheat-beer

I brewed a great american wheat beer over the summer, and got to thinking about winter brew time.

Is there such a thing as a dark wheat beer?

I see a few recipes on brewtoad but not much. It doesnt really seem to be a "thing". Maybe I'm using the wrong terminology in my search? Perhaps there's something else I should consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  It's called dunkelweizen.  Made with wheat malt and Munich malt.  http://wiki.homebrewersassociation.org/15BDunkelweizen